# Android built-in apache vs latest stable apache

Tags: android, apache, httpclient

I would like to research what built-in apache version used in Android and is there any sence to change it on latest stable apache jar from apache website. Current problem with which I have faced is quite big delay when executes post request. I have read a lot of post in stackoverflow concerning it and some users said that from version 4.1.1 this problem fixed.  I have tried to put latest stable apache client and core jars to my project, add them to dependencies but it seems there is still using android built-in apache. How to use third-party apachy jar forcely?

My httpClient:

```
import com.example.restservice.service.EasySSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

import java.security.KeyStore;

public class HttpUtils {
private static DefaultHttpClient client;

public static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (client != null)
        return client;

    try {
        // here we can set a custom keystore if we need to
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new EasySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        client = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
    return client;
}
}
```

SSLSoket:

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class EasySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

public EasySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    super(truststore);
    TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] {
        tm
    }, null);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a [jar](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) with instructions.

Include in your android project and change import statements as indicated in the docs in the link.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this lib but it doesn`t help me despite it has the last stable apache version. I have found only one logical answer for myself - I tried to execute requests throughout local server which installed on not so good hardware, I think. Because when I try to execute the same request throughout live server everything is fired like a shortgun.

Comment: if u suspect server issues, you should remove android from the picture and just use curl/wget to be sure that your server is responding as necessary. then go to the android client

Comment: Check it with curl for both servers. Almost the same result ~500-700ms for both.If send post requests via android then maybe ~500- a few or more minutes for live and local servers correspondingly.

Comment: if curl using -v is good , then u can turn on wire, header logging in the httpclient jar by recompiling it. see my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594470/android-testing-httppost-string-for-debugging-purposes/10640779#10640779 . You will see same trace in android WIRE logs as you see using curl -v